# Network-wide feature request to support TeX in tables

Tags: discussion, stackexchange

Many of us here frequently use MathJax, whether for this site or another site on the SE Network.

Recently SE added support for tables, but ignored the needs of the TeX community, who wish to be able to type TeX symbols/formulas/etc. as well.

#### [This is the feature request on Meta.SE, to support MathJax in tables](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/357525/391772).

Here's some network-wide examples where such support would be needed (please add anymore if you're aware of any!):

- https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/1720/5
- https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/1247/5
- https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/3857/5
- https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/361/5

Comment: While I understand your intent is to pre-empt us being interested in this issue, but advertising individual meta.SE posts here seems like a bad idea to me. Those who are interested in meta.SE will already have looked there.

Comment: @Raphael Not 100% of them.

Comment: Let me put it differently: you're not a member of _this_ community. You came here to advertise a feature request of yours. Even _if_ some of us would agree, that's still posting in bad faith. Hence my downvote.

Comment: @Raphael I have not posted anything in bad faith. Your comment and actions are *unwelcoming* and violate the Stack Exchange Code of Conduct. If you wish, we can check with a CM what they think.

Comment: @user1271772 While I wouldn't call this "bad faith" personally, I do agree with Raphael that this post doesn't seem entirely appropriate. If something is relevant for multiple sites, [meta.se] is the right place to discuss it. I can understand that it may sometimes be a good idea to approach individual communities directly, but it does not appear to be nessecary here. At the least, I would have waited until the discussion on meta.se showed to what extent this feature was intended to be supported.

Comment: @Discretelizard I very much disagree with you.

Answer (score 1):

I already made a comment on Meta.SE that I would expect this to work. So, while we're here anyway, let's see if it just works.

| TSP solution | Running time |
| --- | --- |
| Naive brute force | $O(n!)$ |
| DP | $O(n^2\cdot 2^n)$ |
| Selling on Ebay | $O(1)$ |

(Inspired by https://xkcd.com/399/ )

Comment: There is a slight [bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/357525/391772) when MathJax is in the header though. It seems.